# Lag spikes with filter: drop-shadow() in Chrome only

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-filters

I use a `filter: drop-shadow()` on active header links in combination with a background gradient and `background-clip: text` (thus, `text-shadow` cannot be used, as it would render in front of the gradient). I also use a scrollspy to update the header links and indicate the currently active one. This however produces large lag spikes in Chrome only. It works fine with Edge and Firefox. Why is this and how can it be prevented. (I already push the rendering to the GPU using `will-change: transform`.

A live example can be viewed at <kbd>[beta.jonaskohl.de](https://beta.jonaskohl.de/)</kbd>

---

## EDIT

Below is a snippet of the relevant code. **However, I could not reproduce the problem in the snippet. This only happens on my real page.**

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".link").forEach(lnk => {
  lnk.addEventListener("click", ev => {
    ev.preventDefault()
  })
})

addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section")
  for (let i = sections.length; i-- > 0;) {
    const sec = sections[i]
    const rect = sec.getBoundingClientRect()
    if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight / 2 >= rect.y + window.scrollY) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".active.link").forEach(lnk => {
        lnk.classList.remove("active")
      })
      document.querySelectorAll(".link")[i].classList.add("active")
      break
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#link-list {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.link.active {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px #00f);
  color: #00f;
}

.section {
  padding-top: 20vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ccf, #eef);
}
```

```html
<ul id="link-list">
  <li><a href="#" class="active link">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="section" id="sec1">Section 1</div>
<div class="section" id="sec2">Section 2</div>
<div class="section" id="sec3">Section 3</div>
<div class="section" id="sec4">Section 4</div>
<div class="section" id="sec5">Section 5</div>
```

Comment: could you post some example code in the form of a snippet?

Comment: @Grey see my edit

Comment: your page works fine on my Chrome/Windows 10 setup

Comment: Also having a similar problem. Something to do with filter and drop-shadow. Even when my elements that used filter with drop-shadow were on rendered on the page, it caused intense lag. I've just removed the css for now.

Comment: @JonathanSweetman Same here. Removed the css. I tried `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 250px black` but it's not the same